# Prevent loading dynamic contnet in bootstrap tab twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap tab that loads dynamic page content inside it with pagination . I am using codigniter framework . The flowing jquery works fine loading content in specific tab but what i have noticed in firebug that whenever i switch to another tab and then get back to previous one then it loads the tab content again .

How can i prevent loading the previous tab from loading again when clicked .

Here is my page ..

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">    
        <li id="home"><a href="#home"  class="active" data-toggle="tab" id="page">Home</a></li>
        <li id="foo"><a href="#get_all_division" data-toggle="tab" id="page">Foo</a></li>
        <li id="bar"><a href="#get_all_district" data-toggle="tab" id="page">Bar</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home"></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="get_all_division"></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="get_all_district"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var baseURL = 'http://allinfo/area/';
        //load content for first tab and initialize
            $('#get_all_division').load(baseURL+'get_all_division', function() {
                $('#myTabs').tab(); //initialize tabs
            }); 

        $('#get_all_division').on('click', 'a.page', function() {
            $('#get_all_division').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;

        });

            $('#get_all_district').load(baseURL+'get_all_district', function() {
                $('#myTabs').tab(); //initialize tabs
            }); 


        $('#get_all_district').on('click', 'a.page', function() {
            $('#get_all_district').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
        });

        $('#myTabs').bind('show', function(e) {    
           var pattern=/#.+/gi //use regex to get anchor(==selector)
           var contentID = e.target.toString().match(pattern)[0]; //get anchor         
           //load content for selected tab
            $(contentID).load(baseURL+contentID.replace('#',''), function(){
                $('#myTabs').tab(); //reinitialize tabs
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use .empty() to remove the loaded content once the tab is hidden using a callback, or when another tab is clicked

```
$('#get_all_district').load(baseURL+'get_all_district', function() {
            $('#get_all_division').empty();
            $('#myTabs').tab(); //initialize tabs
 });
```

Comment: i dont want to empty the content . Just once it loaded don't want to load it again when clicked .

Comment: then you might want to add a count to check if the element has been clicked check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcferrans/XmbMU/) , if you have another click event for the second tab you must initialize a second count so it isn't affected by the content loaded in the other one... Hope it helps!